# focus input by press label using css

Tags: html, css

So the question is like this, how can I make user input area focused by pressing the label near it with css only?

Example:
username: **some textbox**

*pressing the "username" text will lead the focus to the textbox.

Comment: Hi, You'll need to provide some code, otherwise it'll be difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: This is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/TYhnb/1611/

What i need there to happen is: click on the text will make the textbox on focus, by css only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid tomato;
}
input {
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<p>First method simply wrap input with label</p>

<label>Username
  <input type="text" placeholder="username">
</label>

<p>Second method by for and id if they are two seprate elements</p>

<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username">
```

Comment: was happy to help you :) do accept my answer if this worked for you